# Table View Customization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating an application, and I have a form that needs to be filled out.  I would like to implement a solution similar to the photo below. In particular I want to implement the top section.  The photo right next to the table cells.

Any suggestions or ideas how how to do this to a table view.  I know its a group table, but I never seen the cells push over like that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the top section is one tableView. It's likely a grouped table (First, Last Initial) with a section header (Name) and a UIImageView next to it (Add Photo). If the entire thing moves up and down (scrollable) then it's likely also embedded in a ScrollView.

Comment: I never noticed that it scrolls

Comment: You can adjust the top tableView (First, Last Initial) by adding a tableView and sizing it in Storyboard or programmatically changing the CGRect to position it off to the right.

Comment: use tableViewName.frame = CGRectMake (#,#,#,#) to move the table programmatically.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, it does look like two tableviews now

Answer (score 1):

the top section is probably one cell with a `UIImageView` and a `UITableView` embedded inside of it. I guess the only way to achieve that top part is to create it a separate `UIView` and add it to the cell's `contentView`.

Answer (score 1):

With everything programming, there are many ways to skin a cat. If I were to approach this problem, I'd use a grouped table view style, have one cell in the 0th section that says: "Join by filling ..." and has no section header, 1 cell in the 1st section with an image placeholder for the user and has no section header, then some text fields made to look like a grouped table view cell on the right. Then the 2nd section would have what looks like 3 standard ios cells and a section header that is a label that says "Contact Info".

Sometimes you need to customize things not the way the iOS platform predicted you would (referring to 1st section)

Answer (score 0):

One way: add button, name and photo elements as a tableHeaderView.

Another one: don't use UITableView for everything. UIScrollView with manual layout would be easier in this case.